# Making a filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some kind of a filter, and I need some help with minimum change on my codes. I believe there must be a practical solution for what I want to do, and wanted to ask for your correction, please.

Button01 hides/shows all elements with the class name filter01,
Button02 hides/shows all elements with the class name filter02,
So, both of the buttons have control over ElementX.
What I want to do is, when a button is clicked once, ElementX must remain hidden until it's clicked again, even when the other button is also clicked after.

HTML:

```
<div class="button01" onclick="filter01()">Filter 01</div>
<div class="button02" onclick="filter02()">Filter 02</div>

<div class="filter01 filter02">ElementX</div></a>
```

JS:

```
function filter01() {
    var i;
    var filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter01");
    for (i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        if (filter[i].style.display) {filter[i].style.display = null; button01.style.color = null;}
        else {filter[i].style.display = "none"; button01.style.color = "rgb(200,200,200)}
    }
}
function filter02() {
    var i;
    var filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter02");
    for (i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        if (filter[i].style.display) {filter[i].style.display = null; button02.style.color = null;}
        else {filter[i].style.display = "none"; button.style.color = "rgb(200,200,200)}
    }
}
```

Comment: the goto solution for this type of problem is to have the target element hold a number, and both buttons have a unique value to increment / decrement the target's number by. If the number is greater than 0 let's say, then the target would be supressed. And if you use (non-overlaping) 2, 4, 6, 8, 16, 64.. the active buttons can be reverse calculated using the target's supression variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would organise the event listening outside of the HTML. Instead define a data attribute on the buttons that determines what they hide. Handle the button clicks in a single function, which will then read the data attribute.

Define a Set that has all the selectors that select items that must be hidden. And toggle set elements in the click handler.

When adding a selector to hide, then just select those elements and hide them. If however, the selector is removed from the set, then first naively show those elements again, but then use the set to hide all elements that are selected by one of the selectors in the set.

Snippet:

```js
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".filterbutton")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", filter);
}

let filters = new Set;

function toggleDisplay(selector, display) {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let elem of elems) {
        elem.style.display = display;
    }
}

function filter() {
    let filterSelector = this.dataset.filter;
    let show = filters.delete(filterSelector);
    this.style.color = show ? "" : "rgb(200,200,200)";
    if (!show) {
        filters.add(filterSelector); // toggle this filter
    } else {
        toggleDisplay(filterSelector, "");
    }
    if (filters.size) {
        toggleDisplay([...filters].join(","), "none");
    }
}
```

```css
.filterbutton { 
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter01">Filter 01</div>
<div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter02">Filter 02</div>
<div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter03">Filter 03</div>

<div class="filter01 filter02 filter03">This element has filter01, filter02 and filter03</div>
<div class="filter01 filter02">This element has filter01 and filter02</div>
<div class="filter01 filter03">This element has filter01 and filter03</div>
<div class="filter02 filter03">This element has filter02 and filter03</div>
<div class="filter01">This element has filter01 only</div>
<div class="filter02">This element has filter02 only</div>
<div class="filter03">This element has filter03 only</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works perfectly! I will click the accepted answer button, but I'd like to ask for your help for one more thing. Do you maybe know how can I disable a button automatically when all of its associated elements are already hidden by other buttons? I mean, e.g. when there's no visible element that `button01` can hide/show, can we gray it out automatically like it's also clicked?

Comment: Sure that is possible. After every change, you'd need to iterate the buttons and check for each if they would bring any change when clicked. If not, disable them, otherwise enable them. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question about it, showing your attempt, and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I just opened a question for this subject specifically.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [trincots code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72924303/6567275) but filtered with CSS not in JS.

```js
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".filterbutton")) {
  button.addEventListener("click", filter);
}

function filter() {
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle(this.dataset.filter);
}
```

```css
.filterbutton {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.container.filter01 .filter01,
.container.filter02 .filter02,
.container.filter03 .filter03 {
  display: none;
}

.container.filter01 .filterbutton[data-filter=filter01],
.container.filter02 .filterbutton[data-filter=filter02],
.container.filter03 .filterbutton[data-filter=filter03] {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter="filter01">Filter 01</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter="filter02">Filter 02</div>
  <div class="filterbutton" data-filter="filter03">Filter 03</div>

  <div class="filter01 filter02 filter03">This element has filter01, filter02 and filter03</div>
  <div class="filter01 filter02">This element has filter01 and filter02</div>
  <div class="filter01 filter03">This element has filter01 and filter03</div>
  <div class="filter02 filter03">This element has filter02 and filter03</div>
  <div class="filter01">This element has filter01 only</div>
  <div class="filter02">This element has filter02 only</div>
  <div class="filter03">This element has filter03 only</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This method looks really awesome, thank you! Do you think there could be a solution with this method for my question in the following article as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928589

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you wanted? I have used `window.getComputedStyle()` method to get the **pointerEvents** of the other button so I can toggle it according to its value. Same for other button as well. Check it out once.

```js
function filter01() {
    var i;
    var filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter01");
    for (i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        if (filter[i].style.display) {
            filter[i].style.display = null; 
            filter[i].style.color = null;
        } else {
            filter[i].style.display = "none"; 
            filter[i].style.color = "rgb(200,200,200)";
        }
    }
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button02");
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(buttons[0]);
    if(styles.pointerEvents === 'auto') {
        buttons[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    } else if(styles.pointerEvents === 'none') {
        buttons[0].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
 
}

function filter02() {
    var i;
    var filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter02");
    for (i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        if (filter[i].style.display) {
            filter[i].style.display = null; 
            filter[i].style.color = null;
        }
        else {
            filter[i].style.display = "none"; 
            filter[i].style.color = "rgb(200,200,200)"
        }
    }

    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button01");
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(buttons[0]);
    if(styles.pointerEvents === 'auto') {
        buttons[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    } else if(styles.pointerEvents === 'none') {
        buttons[0].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="button01" onclick="filter01()">Filter 01</div>
    <div class="button02" onclick="filter02()">Filter 02</div>

    <div class="filter01 filter02">ElementX</div></a>
```