# Automatically hide a button once there's no associated element left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of several elements, and some controlling buttons that can hide/show these elements. Some buttons have control over just one element, while others have multiple elements.

What does my code do:

- Button01 hides/shows ElementX and ElementY,
- Button02 hides/shows only ElementY.
- Once Button01 is clicked, both of the elements are hidden, and clicking Button02 doesn't change anything until Button01 is clicked again.

What I want to do:

- Once Button01 hides ElementX and ElementY, Button02 must also be grayed out automatically because its associated element is gone.
- And then, clicking Button02 should bring ElementY back and enable Button01 too since one of the associated elements of Button01 is back.

```js
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".filterbutton")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", filter);
}

let filters = new Set;

function toggleDisplay(selector, display) {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let elem of elems) {
        elem.style.display = display;
    }
}

function filter() {
    let filterSelector = this.dataset.filter;
    let show = filters.delete(filterSelector);
    this.style.color = show ? "" : "rgb(200,200,200)";
    if (!show) {
        filters.add(filterSelector); // toggle this filter
    } else {
        toggleDisplay(filterSelector, "");
    }
    if (filters.size) {
        toggleDisplay([...filters].join(","), "none");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter01">Filter01</div>
<div class="filterbutton" data-filter=".filter02">Filter02</div>

<div class="filter01">ElementX</div>
<div class="filter01 filter02">ElementY</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you have in doing this? Is it the styling? Is it a problem in the code you have tried with? Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Can you please add a concrete scenario where a button would get disabled. I mean, with concrete `div` and classes, and sequence of clicking the buttons?

Comment: I don't want any button to be disabled, just grayed out automatically once it's associated element is hidden by another button. I tried to explain the scenario in a clearer way. Please check the question again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compare the shown elements with the filters on each button when a button gets clicked. See the solution below

```js
const btns = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName( 'filterbutton' ) );
const els = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName( 'element' ) );

document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  const target = event.target.parentElement;

  if ( target.hasAttribute('data-filter') ) {

    const filter = target.getAttribute( 'data-filter' ).split(" ");

    /* If button is active remove matching elements else show */
    !target.classList.contains( 'hide' )
      ? filter.forEach( el => els[el - 1].classList.add( 'hide' ) )
      : filter.forEach( el => els[el - 1].classList.remove( 'hide' ) );

    btns.forEach( btn => {
      const filter = btn.getAttribute( 'data-filter' ).split(" ");
      
      /* Empty array to push true/false if buttons matching elements are visible */
      const matches = [];
      filter.forEach( match => matches.push( els[match - 1].classList.contains( 'hide' ) ) );
      
      /* If any matches are visible button is active */
      matches.includes( false )
        ? btn.classList.remove( 'hide' )
        : btn.classList.add( 'hide' );
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font-family: monospace; margin: 0 } hr { margin: 1em 0 }

:root { --transTime: .25s; --transFunction: ease-in-out }

#filters, #elements { display: flex; gap: 1em }

.filterbutton, .element {
  --trans: opacity var(--transTime) var(--transFunction);
  transition: var(--trans); -o-transition: width var(--trans); -moz-transition: var(--trans); -webkit-transition: var(--trans);
}

.filterbutton {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: .375em;
  color: black;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.filterbutton.hide { opacity: .5 }

.filterbutton span::before {
  border-radius: .375em;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.filterbutton span:first-of-type { display: inline }
.filterbutton span:last-of-type { display: none }

.filterbutton.hide span:first-of-type { display: none }
.filterbutton.hide span:last-of-type { display: inline }

.element {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.element.hide { opacity: 0 }
```

```html
<div id="filters">
  <button class="filterbutton" type="button" data-filter="1 2 3 4">
    <span>Hide</span><span>Show</span> All
  </button>
  <button class="filterbutton" type="button" data-filter="1">
    <span>Hide</span><span>Show</span> 1
  </button>
  <button class="filterbutton" type="button" data-filter="2 3">
    <span>Hide</span><span>Show</span> 2 & 3
  </button>
  <button class="filterbutton" type="button" data-filter="4">
    <span>Hide</span><span>Show</span> 4
  </button>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="elements">
  <article class="element">Element 1</article>
  <article class="element">Element 2</article>
  <article class="element">Element 3</article>
  <article class="element">Element 4</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks great, but gives some minor incompatibility issues with my codes, and I couldn't optimize by myself :( Can `#filters button` and `#elements article` have opacity: 1 by default in css? And rather than using `document.getElementById( 'filters' ).children`, can you get all classes named `filter-button` instead? (buttons are not the only children of my `filters` div)

Comment: @tez I updated the answer to use class `filterbutton` like in your original question. Also everything is visible by default now and will add class of `hide` when conditions have been met

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction, but I just realized that I missed an important part on your codes. Each elements must have `filter01`, `filter02`, `filter03` etc kind of class names that serve as their category indicators (please see my code). This is how I put them into categories. They're not sorted regularly, hence I can't filter them according to their numerical orders on the list

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given a specific problem that can be expressed by code, the answer can only be given algorithmically:

Аdd class `active` to the visible elements. after clicking the filter button, remove this class from the filtered elements. at the end of filtering, go through all the buttons and if the result is document.querySelectorAll('.active.filter') empty set - disabled the filter button.